# WxPython - Dialog, module object is not Callable

Tags: module, dialog, wxpython, callable

i have a custom Dialog class in file Dialog1.py

```
class Dialog1(wx.Dialog):
def __init__(self, prnt):
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, id=wxID_DIALOG1, name='Dialog1', parent=prnt,
          pos=wx.Point(110, 140), size=wx.Size(400, 498),
          style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE, title='Dialog1')
```

in other file Frame - wx.Frame with button

```
self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Dec, id=wxID_FRAME3BUTTON1)
```

and method  to show Dialog

```
def Dec(self, event):
    import Dialog1
    self.dialog = Dialog1(self)
    self.dialog.ShowModal()
    #dialog.Destroy()
    return True
```

and When I Push this Button i have a error;

```
TypeError: 'module' is not Callable
```

Why?, please Help Me

Edit: Ok is work now, to much copy-paste method ... Sorry

```
REMOVE THIS QUESTION
```

Comment: voting to close, at the request of the author

Answer (score 1):

"'module' is not Callable" errors typically mean you did something like this:

```
import Foo
...
foo = Foo()
```

... when you should have done something like:

```
from Foo import Foo
...
foo = Foo
```

In other words, you've got a bad import statement somewhere, where you're importing a whole library rather than a class or function from that module.

My guess is, you have a file named Dialog1.py that has the class Dialog1 in it. Which means you need to do:

```
from Dialog1 import Dialog1
...
self.dialog = Dialog1(self)
```